# EF Migration Failed - How I can see Entity Framework's migration logs

Tags: .net, entity-framework, .net-core

I'm following this tutorial: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/get-started/aspnetcore/new-db

Everything looks fine. I've installed .NET Core, Entity Framework (and EF.Tools) and MSSQL, the project is built correctly and the DB is online, but when I run the `Add-Migration` command I have this output:

```
PM> Add-Migration base -Verbose
Using framework 'netcoreapp1.0'
Using data directory '<root_path>\.\bin\Debug\netcoreapp1.0'
Build started...
Build failed.
```

When I start the projet (F5) it compiles and run well (but without the migration), same with `dotnet build`:

```
Compilation succeeded.
0 Warning(s)
0 Error(s)
Time elapsed 00:00:01.6124860
```

I don't have any error message, the `dotnet restore` has completed without failure. Anyone knows where I can find the migration logs or how to display more informations ?

Comment: It says your build failed, fix that first.

Comment: try -Verbose   ...

Comment: @DavidG It compiles without errors when I run the solution (F5), only the Add-Migration command is currently failing.

Comment: @ErikEJ Thanks, I've edited my post but it didn't tell me what is failing :(

Comment: F5 won't necessarily build everything. Try building your entire solution or run a `dotnet build` command.

Comment: @DavidG Compilation succeeded with dotnet buid too. It looks weird. I'll try to reinstall complety Visual Studio. If It don't resolve my issue I'll open an issue on EF's Github. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Do you have anything in your output window when it fails?

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44785540/ef-core-add-migration-build-failed

Answer (score 1):

Try `-Verbose` for more information.