# EF Core add-migration Build Failed

Tags: .net, entity-framework, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-migrations

I have a developer that is getting "Build failed." when running add-migration in a .NET Core EF project, with no explanation of why the build failed. How do you troubleshoot this error?

This is what he gets in the Package Manager Console:[image]

**Additional information**:

We have a few other developers using the same solution code (myself included) that have not issues with add-migration.

This is what I see in Package Manager Console:[image]

We've verified that the project builds, and the entire solution builds. We've done "dotnet restore" and rebuild all multiple times, in addition to restarting VS2015. We've verified that the correct default solution is selected both in Solution Explorer, and in the Package Manager Console drop-down. We've verified that he has the correct SDK installed on his machine. I'm at a loss as to what to check next...any time I've had a failure during add-migration I've gotten enough information to point me in the direction of what to check, but just "Build failed." is a fairly useless error output.

Comment: You should try to use the -v option and see if you get more details about the error.

Comment: When I get build errors on just a single machine, I start be deleting personal solution file (.suo). You will need to reset the startup project after that.

Comment: We used the -v option, we did not get more details about the error.

Comment: Deleting the .suo file didn't change anything.

Comment: execute "dotnet build" command and see more details about the error.

Comment: Solved this problem by rebuild the project 'dotnet run'.

Comment: The -v option helped! A note to future travelers, you may want to redirect the output to a text file, the problem is probably near the top of the output. And -v, the verbose flag, means what it says. It is very, very verbose.

Comment: "dotnet build" worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developer ended up un-mapping the project from TFS, deleting it, and re-mapping it. It's now working for him.

Comment: This would be my *last* resort.

Answer (score 127):

It's because of other projects in your solutions. e.g If you have two projects in your solution as Project A and Project B. If Project A is not successful build and then Project B data migration will fail. So you should unload Project A and add the migration to Project B again.

I think this is not a good answer but hope this help.

Comment: I had an unwanted database project in my solution which was added as a random test and I was not aware of it! When i built the solution, no error shown but the `add-migration` Build Failed! After i remove that temp project, everything works!

Comment: I had the `dotnet run watch` running and was holding everything up

Comment: The easiest way to identify the problem:

1. open command-line
2.  navigate to project folder where you want to add the migration
3.  run `dotnet build`

The output will show all errors and warnings

Answer (score 55):

I had the exact same problem (.NET Core 2.0.1).

Sometimes it helps if the project is rebuilt.

I also encounter the problem when I opened the project in 2 Visual Studios.
Closing one Visual Studio fixed the error.

- Ctrl + C (first stop the application from running, this alone might be enough!)
- dotnet run build
- dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate

Comment: Rebuilding the project after changing the connection string on the `appsettings.json` works for me.

Comment: I had the solution open in VS2019 and simply closing VS2019 made the command work.

Comment: I closed all open visual studios, it fixed.

Answer (score 29):

I was struggling with this one while using Visual Studio 2019 version 16.5.0.

What solved it finally:

- Close Visual Studio;
- Reopen Visual Studio;
- Make sure you right click the Solution if you have multiple projects and select **`Rebuild Solution`**.

Note that I tried doing a `Rebuild Solution` before and that did not catch the error. So it's important to close VS and reopen it.

It then showed the error that was causing **`add-migration`** command to fail with `Build failed` message.

Comment: thanks! simple ... it was just a matter of closing and reopening visual studio :)

Comment: That you very much!

Answer (score 23):

I suggest adding `-v` to have more info.

In my example, I had to add 
`<LangVersion>latest</LangVersion>` to my projects, as this was missing from some of them.

Answer (score 18):

Try these steps:

1. Clean the solution.
2. Build every project separately.
3. Resolve any errors if found (sometimes, VS is not showing errors until you build it separately).
4. Then try to run migration again.

Answer (score 15):

In my situation it was the error

```
namespace aspnetcore does not exist .. are you missing a reference?
```

I have figured it out by adding the -v (or --verbose) flag to the dotnet ef command.

Comment: adding -v saved me.

Answer (score 12):

In my case, the application was running. Apparently, it needs to be stopped. Weird error message anyways.

Comment: Same. IISExpress was hosting my web. Closed VS2019 (which closes IISExpress) and the migration succeeded.

Comment: Same here. I closed VS2022 and Sign out my PC (which closes every running program) then the migration succeeded

Answer (score 10):

Had the same situation.
This helped:

1. Open Package Manager Console
2. Change directory to **Migrations** folder:

   ```
   cd C:\YourSolution\YourProjectWithMigrations
   ```
3. Enter in PM:

   ```
   dotnet ef migrations add YourMigrationName
   ```

Answer (score 10):

Open Output window in Visual Studio and check your build log. In my case, even though my current configuration was `Release`, `Add-Migration` built the project in `Debug`, which had an error. For some reason, VS didn't display the error anywhere except Output window for me.

Comment: Check in Output windows is professional way. We can know exact root cause why build failed.

Comment: So stupid of me not to think of it but there was no hint to look at that window (it was hidden by the PM Console.. But many thanks for mentioning it!

Answer (score 7):

Got the same error when I tried to run `add-migration`. Make sure that you don't have any syntax errors in your code.

I had a syntax error in my code, and after I fixed it, I was able to run `add-migration`.

Comment: I made some hefty changes to models and (re)building would not show any errors, but add-migration just said "Build failed". Running the command line yielded the actual errors: in this case it was the Razor **Views**! Fixed those and add-migration worked again.

Answer (score 3):

Most likely that there is an existing error in your code. Try rebuilding first and correct all the errors.

Happened to me, I am trying to rollback migration but I have not corrected the errors in the code yet.

Answer (score 3):

Just got into this issue.
In my case, I was debugging my code and it was making my migrations fail.

Since in Visual Studio Code, the debugger is so low-profile (only a small bar), I didn't realize about this until I read some questions and decided to look better.

Answer (score 2):

I had exact same error but I am using Visual Studio Community 2017 Version 15.2 (26430.14) to build .Net Core projects.

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC web project and a separate security project using ASP.NET Core Identity. The web project contains connection string in aspsettings.json config file.

I also installed **Bundler & Minifier** and **Web Essentials 2017** extensions in Visual Studio so that I can compile, minify and bundle my assets and put them to wwwroot.

I figured out it was the MSBuild those 2 extensions secretly download that caused the problem, because I had **Enable Bundle on Build** and **Enable Compile on Build** on. After I disable that, everything works fine.

Probably not the cause to your problem, but might be worthy to just give it a try.

Answer (score 2):

I think this happened to me when I tried to run `dotnet ef migrations add xyz` whilst it was already running.

In the end, just to be sure, I stopped the currently running instance, then ran it again to ensure it was rebuilt, stopped it again and I was able to run the `dotnet ef migrations add` command

Answer (score 2):

Try saving DataContext.cs first. It worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

In My case, add the package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools fixed problem

Answer (score 1):

I think the 2 commands below always work (if you run them at project's folder)

- dotnet ef migrations add  (database object fron ApplicationDbContextDBContext)
- dotnet ef database update

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error.  What I did, I corrected the error the one I have in code, and rebuilt the project. Then I ran the ms-dos command and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error. There were no errors during the build proccess. I closed the Visual Studio and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when running:
 `dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`

so what I did is tried to build the project using:
 `dotnet build` command.

It throws an error : `Startup.cs(20,27): error CS0103: bla bla` for example. which you can trace to find the error in your code.

Then i refactored the code and ran:
 `dotnet build` again 
to check any errors until there is no errors and build is succeded.
Then ran:
`dotnet ef migrations add InitialCreate`
then the build succeded.

Answer (score 1):

this is because deleting projects or class libraries from solution and adding projects after deleting with same name.
            best thing is delete solution file and add projects to it.this works for me
(I did this using vsCode)

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had couple of such errors:

```
The process cannot access the file 'C:\xxx\bin\Debug\netcoreapp3.1\yyy.dll' 
because it is being used by another process. [C:\zzz.csproj]
```

I was able to see those errors only after adding -v parameter.

The solution was to shutdown the Visual Studio and run the command again.

Comment: Thanks for the "-v" switch. That helped! This poorly designed, manual EF solution by Microsoft means a million things can go wrong that block the "migration" junk files from getting built. In my case it didn't like some custom logging I was doing in my Main method. Who knew! Your -v or verbose allowed me to see all the errors and track it down. Otherwise this mess by Microsoft would have eaten up another half of my day :)

Answer (score 1):

In my case rebuilding the **Project** worked fine. Running the project worked fine too and executing some endpoints worked.

But still on update-database it would say "Build Failed" without any clarification, even with -Verbose added to the command.

At the end it happened that there was an error in Unit Test project that would (for some reason) cause "Build Failed" error.

Since I have multiple projects under the same **Solution**, I would just rebuild the Project that I am currently working on. It appears that when this error happens that it would be better to rebuild whole **Solution** and resolve errors...

Answer (score 0):

maybe it cause because of you did not add this in YOUR_PROJECT.csproj

```
<ItemGroup>

<DotNetCliToolReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools.Dotnet" Version="2.0.2" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have code generation inside startup.cs. Also, make sure to use `<TargetFramework>` if you are using multiple target frameworks `<TargetFrameworks>`. You can temporary comment `<TargetFrameworks>` when running add-migration.

Also, if the PropertyGroup has Condition, you need to comment/remove them when running ef migration

**Example**

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.1</TargetFramework>
</PropertyGroup>

<ItemGroup>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
 <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite" Version="2.1.2" />
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.Design" Version="2.1.3" />
 </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I fixed it by stopping the project build. After that it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this could also be caused by BuildEvents. For me I was referencing $(SolutionDir) there. With a regular build this variable has value, but running dotnet * commands is done at project level apparently. $(SolutionDir) comes out like *Undefined* in verbose mode (-v). This seems like a bug to me.

Answer (score 0):

1: I was getting the error:
PM> Add-Migration "InitialDB"
Build failed.
2:The error was the "(" missing. I corrected that and error is gone.

so the error you can see the error in the output. The error was because of the code issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was failing because an unrelated project in the solution was failing. Unloading that project and running the command again worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was because i had error somewhere.. Like missing coma in db config file, so VS didn't throw exception until build

So just try to run your code...

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question.

Please ensure that your answer improves upon other answers already present in this question.

Answer (score 0):

Same errors for me. I tried -v but nothing. Then I realised I had changed the model so much that the controller was showing errors.

Once I fixed the errors in the controller it worked.

Answer (score 0):

It might have many possibilities I guess. In my case, it was due packages versions inbalance

I had

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.3"/>
```

I just need it to downgrade the core Design package to 3.1.1 to match the upper core version

```
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.1.1"/>
<PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.1.1"/>
```

Then it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

Only clearing Visual Studio cache helped me

1. Close Visual Studio (ensure devenv.exe is not present in the Task Manager)
2. Delete the %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\16.0\ComponentModelCache directory.
3. Restart Visual Studio. You could also need to cleanup your user's temp folder. It is usually located under %USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\Temp.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you have opted .NET Core tool collect usage data for Windows improvement then you can use `dotnet build` to get the missing/persisting problem.

Answer (score 0):

In my case it was sonarqube dependencies that were missing. When I built the project in Rider it succeeded but failed when triggered the build (dotnet build) from terminal. This was caused by a incorrect setup in Rider. The solution was to trigger a sonar scan in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same error. The issue in my case was that I was running my backend server with the `watch` build and since `.Net` Build was overburdened, it was unable to execute the add migration command at the same time, therefore I had to stop running the application and then run the migration command again.

Answer (score 0):

Also, don't forget to check in what folder you are now in the package manager (PM) console. You can use "ls" command in windows to check the list of subfolders.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio, open the *Output window* and select *Build* from *Show output from*. There you can see why the build failed.

I had a test project and it had an error. This is why the build failed when migrating. But my starting project which is the API layer had no error and was built successfully. So I conclude, EF Core Tools builds every project in the solution.
Therefore it is better to check the Build output when a migration fails.